# $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ as a direct product of two subgroups. (Hint: polar form)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism, direct-product

In an abelian group $G,$ let $G^{2} = \{g^2 | g \in G\},$ which is a subgroup. Let $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ denote the rational, real and complex fields, respectively. Let $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ be the positive reals, and $\mathbb{Q}^{+} = \mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{R}^{+}.$

$(a)$ Write $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ as a direct product of two subgroups. (Hint: polar form)\

**My questions are:**

1-I know that I can prove that it is a direct product by either one of those 2 criteria:

{For groups $G,H,K,$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.\

a. $G \cong K \times H.$\

b. $H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK $ and $H \cap K = \{1\}.$

Am I correct ?

2- If I were to use the first criteria, should I only proof that the function $g : \mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}$ defined by $g(e^{it}, r) = r e^{it}, t\in \mathbb{R}$ is an isomorphism only and this is the complete proof?  why we defined $g$ like that?

Comment: First, show that $\mathbb{T}$ and $\mathbb{R}+$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$. Show that your function $g$ is bijective and a homomorphism, and this will give $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ as a direct product of two subgroups.

Comment: but how can I show rigorously that they are subgroups of $\mathbb{C^{*}}$? @JetChung

Comment: Show that the multiplication in the subgroups is closed and show that inverses to all elements exists. Remember, the multiplicative identity of both groups is the real number 1. And you don't really need to prove the group axioms since these are inherited from the group structure of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} = (0, 1]$. We claim that $\mathbb{T}$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$. To see this, note if $x, y \in \mathbb{T}$, then $x+y \equiv x+y -\lfloor x+y \rfloor \in \mathbb{T}$, and if $x \in \mathbb{T}$, then $-x \equiv 1-x \in \mathbb{T}$.

To show $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$, simply note if $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, then $xy \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, and if $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then $\frac{1}{x}\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Now, the function $g: \mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}$ by $(t, r) \mapsto re^{2\pi i t}$ is easily seen to be a bijective homomorphism, so $\mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \cong \mathbb{C}^{*}$.